# How to check missing number in some column

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-native-query

I use Mysql and spring data jpa

I Have Questions about how to find missing data some column

that column attribute is int.

So.if i insert some data in some data column.

number table

```
seq | number | sometext | someData | something | some | some
```

when i insert data like this.

```
1 0 sometext someData  something some some,

2 2 sometext someData  something some some,

3 3 sometext someData  something some some,

4 5 sometext someData  something some some,

5 10 sometext someData  something some some,
```

how to get i missing number column

in spring data jpa native query.

Comment: what number is missing in your example?

Comment: 1,4,6,7,8,9 is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this query

```
SELECT   CONCAT(X.EXPECTED, IF(X.GOT-1>X.EXPECTED, CONCAT(' ~ ',X.GOT-1), '')) AS MISSING
FROM     (
         SELECT
                  @ROWNUM:=@ROWNUM+1 AS EXPECTED,
                  IF(@ROWNUM=B.number , 0, @ROWNUM:=B.number ) AS GOT
         FROM     (SELECT @ROWNUM:=0) AS A
                  INNER JOIN YOUR_TABELE B
         ORDER BY B.number 
         ) AS X
WHERE X.GOT!=0;
```

Comment: Thank you sour answer But mysql can this query but i can't use jpa native Query
Do you know how to use that Queryuu in spring data jpa

Comment: Well I don't know how to use jpa native query. sorry

Comment: maybe use this
 @ROWNUM \\:=

Comment: there ar occur error could not execute query;
And why jpa find Column 'sequence' not found